# Visual Web Developer 2010 contact us form, need tutorial or example

Tags: visual-studio-2010, forms, contact-form, visual-web-developer-2010

I've googled, but I cannot find a good, short, easy-to-comprehend tutorial on how to make a contact us page in VWD 2010 Express.

I just want a simple form, say, contactengineering.aspx, and when they submit the form, the e-mail gets sent directly to an email addresses of one of our engineers.  I'd like something easy-to-make and quick; the master pages are already made.

Could anybody point me in the right direction here?

Thanks a bunch!

Jason Weber

Comment: Are you wanting to use asp.net MVC? or asp.net webforms? Also, what language? ie C#, VB etc.

Comment: Hi Dessus.  I'm not a professional programmer, and definitely not too intelligent, so I was looking for the simplest tool.  I have MVC 3 tools on my VWD, and I could figure out the tutorial you provided.  I really just want something easy, light, that gets the job done and gets the email sent.  As mentioned, I'm not a programmer, so I really only know basic VWD things.  Thanks for your help, and your time in reading and replying!  I've already bookmarked those links, and I'll delve into 'em once I get a cup of coffee!

Comment: Possibly visual studio light switch is a good starting option too. That is setup for non programmers to setup applications quickly. Possibly that could have a template to do this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for MVC: http://www.frederikvig.com/2010/05/creating-a-contact-form-with-asp-net-mvc/ in combination with this one: http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/08/asp-net-mvc-contact-form/